# how to show dropdown same in all platform using phonegap?

Tags: android, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using drop down using jQuery mobile + phonegap. But my problem is that it is looking different in iOS and android, meaning it uses the native dropdown.

But I think I am using jQuery mobile + phonegap so it should look same in all platform not use native things? Is there any way to show dropdown so that it look same in all platform.

I used this

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only option I know of to have a standard looking dropdown is to not use a dropdown. You would need to create a button that looks like a dropdown and onclick will present a popup div with the options listed. When user selects an option the popup would close and set the value of the button to the selected item.

Kind of a hacky way to do things but like I said. It's the only way I know.

Edit*** Took a lot longer to generate in jsfiddle then I expected but I learned something along the way about its inner button structure and the need to use `span span.ui-btn-text` when editing the button text. [Take a look.](http://jsfiddle.net/gMLDb/)

Comment: can you please give some example on fiddle